# regex in query parameter in Network Inspector Rule

Tags: android-studio, android-debugging, app-inspection

I need to Mock an API with the help of Network Inspector - Rule [Network Inspector - Rule](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/network-profiler#network-inspector-overview), Following Image describes My rule detail :
[image: Need timestamp=anything in the quesry pram of the rule]

IN the query param - service=pfb&language=en-IN&page=0&pageSize=15000&timestamp=*

What I need is to return the same response for any timeStamp, but it's not working.
It takes * for its literal meaning. so the rule stays unapplicable.
any suggestion?

Earlier I used to do the response mocking with charles, but that requires the same wifi on the computer as well as the device.
Right now I am on a mobile network of my phone and create hotspot to use wifi in my computer.